# Check if command is internal in CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a command's name and I need to check if this command is internal. How can I do it in a batch script?

Comment: Check the docs?  :P  Seriously, CMD doesn't change much.  If it's a builtin in one version, it'll be a builtin in later versions.

Comment: One thing I forgot to ask is why? Why do you need this? Maybe there's a better way around this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So after a lot of tweaking, and thanks to the help of @Andriy M, it finally works.

```
@ECHO off

CALL :isInternalCommand dir dirInternal
ECHO is dir internal: %dirInternal%

CALL :isInternalCommand find findInternal
ECHO is find internal: %findInternal%

exit /b 0

:isInternalCommand
SETLOCAL

MKDIR %TEMP%\EMPTY_DIR_FOR_TEST > NUL 2>& 1
CD /D %TEMP%\EMPTY_DIR_FOR_TEST
SET PATH=
%~1 /? > NUL 2>&1
IF ERRORLEVEL 9009 (ENDLOCAL
SET "%~2=no"
) ELSE (ENDLOCAL
SET "%~2=yes"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

---

### OLD SOLUTION

You can use `where`. If it fails, the command is probably internal. If it succeeds, you get the executable path that proves it's not internal.

```
C:\Users\user>where path
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

C:\Users\user>where find
C:\Windows\System32\find.exe
```

**EDIT:** As the comments suggest, this might not be the best solution if you're looking for portability and not just research. So here's another possible solution.

Set `%PATH%` to nothing so `HELP` can't find anything and then run `HELP` on the command you're trying to check.

```
C:\Users\user>set PATH=

C:\Users\user>path
PATH=(null)

C:\Users\user>%WINDIR%\System32\help del
Deletes one or more files.

DEL [/P] [/F] [/S] [/Q] [/A[[:]attributes]] names
[...]

C:\Users\user>%WINDIR%\System32\help find
'find' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

This might still fail if the command doesn't have help.

**EDIT 2:** Never mind, this won't work either. Both cases return `%ERRORLEVEL%=1`.

Comment: `where path` reports wrong if there's actually a program named `path` in the path.

Comment: Windows 7 SP1. Step 1. Running `SET PATH=`. (OK) Step 2. `HELP FIND` -> `'help' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` (oops...)

Comment: That's why you have to run `%WINDIR%\system32\HELP` and not just `HELP`.

Comment: Ah, my fault, missed that, sorry. (Amazing, what was I looking at?)

Comment: As for `ERRORLEVEL`, you are mistaken. The "Not found" case results in ERRORLEVEL=9009, while the successful one in ERRORLEVEL=1. So this is actually an applicable method, good job!

Comment: Sorry again, it was `find /?` that returned 9009. So, yes, a slightly different approach (without `help`), but the basic idea still works (I think).

Comment: Well, we still need `HELP` to get a coherent return value in case it's actually there. I was also trying to avoid actually executing the command in case it's a "bad" one (like `format`, `del`, etc.)

Comment: There are two more points regarding the `/?` method. 1. You should make sure the `%WINDIR%\System32` directory isn't the current one (obviously). 2. An internal command called with `/?` **doesn't change** ERRORLEVEL. So you need to make sure, before you use it, that the current ERRORLEVEL value is not `9009`, or, obviously, you will not be able to tell the new 9009 from the old one.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, lots of good ideas here. But the code can still fail if an executable or batch script exists within the current directory that matches the specified command name. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13205162/1012053) for a solution.

Comment: That's what the CD \ was originally for. But you're right, even the root directory can contain executables. I added a temporary directory.

Answer (score 3):

kichik has a good answer. However, it can give a false positive if there happens to be an executable or batch script within the current directory that matches the supplied command name.

The only way I can think of to avoid that problem is to create a folder that is known to be empty within the `%TEMP%` directory, and then run the test from that folder.

Here is a modified version of kichik's solution that should work.

```
@echo off
setlocal

::Print the result to the screen
call :isInternal find
call :isInternal dir

::Save the result to a variable
call :isInternal find resultFind
call :isInternal dir  resultDir
set result

exit /b

:isInternal  command  [rtnVar]
setlocal
set "empty=%temp%\empty%random%"
md "%empty%"
pushd "%empty%"
set path=
>nul 2>nul %1 /?
if errorlevel 9009 (set rtn=not internal) else (set rtn=internal)
popd
rd "%empty%"
(
  endlocal
  if "%~2" neq "" (set %~2=%rtn%) else echo %1 is %rtn%
)
exit /b 0
```

Here is a script that will simply list all internal commands, assuming that HELP includes a complete list of internal commands.

***Update:*** *Both FOR and IF have special parsing rules that prevent those commands from working if executed via a FOR variable or delayed expansion. I had to rewrite this script to use a CALL and execute the command via a CALL argument instead.*

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "empty=%temp%\empty%random%"
md "%empty%"
pushd "%empty%"
for /f "delims= " %%A in ('help^|findstr /rc:"^[^ ][^ ]*  "') do call :test %%A
popd
rd "%empty%"
exit /b

:test
setlocal
set path=
%1 /? >nul 2>nul
if not errorlevel 9009 echo %1
exit /b 0
```